# Cumulative Abundance curve

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have data of three cumulative fish abundance counts that look like this:

```
Mins    Cumulative.1    Cumulative.2    Cumulative.3
0   0   0   0
5   NA  58  60
10  43  84  84
15  NA  121 96
20  63  128 101
25  NA  136 102
30  70  145 103
```

I am trying to plot them (not necessarily on the same graph) and fit curves of best fit to them.  I know I want a curve that levels off i.e. logarithmic but it won't let me fit one because I have (0,0) values but also x is not a measured variable so this doesn't work.

how can I fit a curve and also find out when it levels off? (i.e. to work out the least time required to get all the fish (or at least a good representation of the population

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a saturation model.

Here's is some example code with comments:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'Mins    Cumulative.1    Cumulative.2    Cumulative.3
0   0   0   0
5   NA  58  60
10  43  84  84
15  NA  121 96
20  63  128 101
25  NA  136 102
30  70  145 103')
plot(Cumulative.3 ~ Mins, data = df)

# fit saturation model
mod <- nls(Cumulative.3 ~ a*Mins / (Mins + b), data = df, start = list(a = 100, b = 5))
summary(mod)
# plot model
plot(Cumulative.3 ~ Mins, data = df)
pdat <- data.frame(Mins = seq(min(df$Mins), max(df$Mins), length.out = 1000))
pdat$fit <- predict(mod, newdata = pdat)
plot(Cumulative.3 ~ Mins, data = df, ylim = c(0, 125))
lines(pdat$Mins, pdat$fit, col = 'darkred', lwd = 2)
# a = saturation level
abline(h = mod$m$getPars()[1], lty = 'dotted')
# b = Mins till 1/2 saturaion level
abline(h = mod$m$getPars()[1]/2, lty = 'dotted')
abline(v = mod$m$getPars()[2], lty = 'dotted')

# Mins till 80% of saturation level is reached:
m = mod$m$getPars()[2]* 0.8 / (1-0.8)
m
abline(h = 0.8*mod$m$getPars()[1])
abline(v = m)
```

[image]

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you